Fedora 40 Hyprland: не работают некоторые сочетания клавиш
Недавно перешел с GNOME на Hyprland, и столкнулся с проблемой: Некоторые функции, которые вызываются сочетанием клавиш, не работают, вылетая с ошибкой:

Pypr can't connect, is daemon running?

Такое проявляется, например, при нажатии Super+shift+enter или super+z.
Что с этим делать?
